# nested Objects and Arrays

Tags: javascript, object, this, nest-nested-object

I cannot seem to find an answer to this and I am confused.

I have the following set up:

```
var object1 = {
    array1: [
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2
        },
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2, val2
        }
    ]

}
```

My question is, when I add "prop3" I want to refer to prop1 and prop2.  I thought I could use `this` as in the below example but it doesn't work.

```
var object1 = {
    array1: [
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            prop3: "I want to include " + this.prop2 + " in this string"
        },
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2, val2
        }
    ]

}
```

I tried `this` because I'm aware that accessing a property within an object works using the `this` keyword.

However `this.prop2` evaluates as `undefined`.  I presume that `this` may not be the whole problem.  As when I try:

```
var object1 = {
    array1: [
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2: val2,
            prop3: "I want to include " + object1.array1[0].prop2 + " in this string"
        },
        {
            prop1: val1,
            prop2, val2
        }
    ]

}
```

With this code I get an error "cannot read property array1 of undefined".  However when I take it out the string, so the rest of my js runs okay, and `console.log(object1.array1[0].prop2`, i get, as expected, `val2`.

Thanks

Comment: It is in fact duplicate question. Anyway following may work for you.       var object1 = {
    array1: [
        {
            prop1 : 13,
            prop2 : 15,
            
        },
        {
            prop1 : 13,
            prop2 :  12,        
        },
    ],
    init: function() {
        this.array1[0].prop3 = "I want to include " + this.array1[0].prop2 + " in this string";
        return this;
    }

}.init();

alert(object1.array1[0].prop3);

Comment: @Arpit thanks.  This will work.  Appreciate your help.